# Call to CLIPS action modify causes the system to hang

Tags: clips

I am modifying templated fact via call to (modify) action but it causes CLIPS to hang.

RULES:

```
(deffunction reset-allowed-values "Resets allowed values"
    ; no argument
    ($?arg)
    (if (eq (any-factp ((?fact model1)) TRUE) TRUE)
        then
            ;T1_1, T2_1, T3_1
            (do-for-all-facts ((?fact ar-node)) (eq ?fact:trip 1)
                (modify ?fact (allowed-values A B C D E F))))
```

MAIN:

```
int main(void) 
{   
    DATA_OBJECT rtn;
    void *env = CreateEnvironment();
    printf("Environment Created!\n");

    EnvSetConserveMemory(env, 1);

    int result = EnvLoad(env, "custom/rules/test.clp");
    if(result == 0) {
        printf("Unable to find the consruct!\n");
        DestroyEnvironment(env);
        return(1);
    } else if(result == -1) {
        printf("Unable to load the consruct!\n");
        DestroyEnvironment(env);
        return(1);
    }
    printf("Construct Loaded!\n");

    EnvReset(env);
    printf("Environment Reset!\n");

    EnvFunctionCall(env,"reset-allowed-values", 0, &rtn);

    printf("CLIPS test done! Used memory %ld bytes.\n", EnvMemUsed(env));

    DestroyEnvironment(env);

  return(0);
}
```

I am currently have no idea why the call to modify causes call to reset-allowed-values not to return. CLIPS is built and running in UBUNTU Linux 32bit. Anyone can help me out on this, all help is very much appreciated. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: Is the reset-allowed-values deffunction the only contents of the file test.clp? It would be helpful to include the deftemplates and deffacts contained in that file.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. You need to include all of the code that's included in test.clp

Comment: Hi All, i already found the caused of the problem it seems in v6.3 the behavior of modify is different than in v6.4. In v6.3 do-all-facts will not exit if the facts are modified. I replaced this with delayed-do-all-facts. I didn't realize that I was using CLIPSIDE v6.4 when I tested the CLIPS construct and CLIPS v6.3 for the embedded part. Thank you very much for your help and time.